# Bootloader Working

Tags: embedded, bootloader, u-boot

I am working on Uboot bootloader. I have some basic question about the functionality of Bootloader and the application it is going to handle:

Q1: As per my knowledge, bootloader is used to download the application into memory. Over internet I also found that bootloader copies the application to RAM and then the application runs from RAM. I am confused with the working of Bootloader...When application is provided to bootloader through serial or TFTP, What happens next, whether Bootloader copies it to RAM first or whether it writes directly to Flash.

Q2: Why there is a need for Bootloader to copy application to RAM and then run the application from RAM? What difficulties we will face if our application runs from FLASH?

Q3: What is the meaning of statement "My application is running from RAM/FLASH"? Is it mean that our application's .text segment or .code segment is in RAM/FLASH? And we are not concerned about .bss section because it is designed to be in RAM.

Thanks
Phogat

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When any hardware system is designed, the designer must consider where the executable code will be located.  The answer depends on the microcontroller, the included memory types, and the system requirements.  So the answer varies from system to system.  Some systems execute code located in RAM.  Other systems execute code located in flash.  You didn't tell us enough about your system to know what it is designed to do.

A system might be designed to execute code from RAM because RAM access times are faster than flash so code can execute faster.  A system might be designed to execute code from flash because flash is plentiful and RAM may not be.  A system might be designed to execute code from flash so that it boots more quickly.  These are just some examples and there are other considerations as well.

RAM is volatile so it does not retain code through a power cycle.  If the system executes code located in RAM then a bootloader is required to obtain and write the code to RAM at powerup.  Flash is non-volatile so execution can start right away at powerup and a bootloader is not necessary (but may still be useful).

Regarding Q3, the answer is yes.  If the system is running from RAM then the .text will be located in RAM (but not until after the bootloader has copied it to there).  If the system is running from flash then the .text section will be located in flash.  The .bss section is variables and will be in RAM regardless of where the .text section is.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, in general a bootloader boots the system, but it might also provide a mechanism for interrupting the default boot path and allow alternate firmware to be downloaded and run instead, as well as other features (like flashing).

Traditional rom had a traditional ram like interface, address, data, chip select, read/write, etc.  And you can still buy rom that way, but it is cheaper from a pin real estate perspective to use something spi or i2c based, which is slower.  Not desireable to run from, but tolerable to read once then run from ram.  newer flash technologies can/have had problems with read-disturb, where if your code is in a tight loop reading the same instructions or for any other reason the flash is being read too fast, the charge can drop such that a read returns the wrong data, potentially causing the program to change course or crash.  Also your PC and other linux platforms are used to copying the kernel from NV storage (hard disk) to ram and then running from there so the copy from flash to ram and run from ram has a comfort level, and is often faster than flash.  So there are many potential reasons to not use flash, but depending on the system it may be possible to run from flash just fine (some systems the flash in question is not accessible directly and not executable, of course SOME rom in that system needed to be executable/bootable).

It simplifies the coding challenges if you program the flash with something that is in ram.  You can create and debug the code one time that reads from ram and writes to flash and reads from flash and writes to ram.  DONE.  Now you can work on separate code that receives data from serial to ram, or from ram to serial. DONE.  Then work on code that does the same over ethernet or usb or whatever DONE.  You dont have to deal with inventing a protocol or solving the problem of timing.  Flash writing is very slow, and even xmodem at a moderate speed can be way too fast, so you have to buffer that data in ram anyway, might as well make the tasks completely separate, instead of an xmodem or any other serial based flash loader with a big ram based fifo, just move the data to ram, then separately go from ram to flash.  Same for other interfaces.  It is technically possible to buffer the data and give the illusion of going from the download interface straight to flash, and depending on the protocol it is technically possible to hold off the sender so that as little as one flash page is required in ram before programming flash.  With the older parallel flashes you could do something pretty cool which I dont think most people figured out.  When you stop writing to the flash page for some known period of time the flash would automatically start to program that page and you have to wait for 10ms or something like that before it is done.  What folks assumed was you had to program sequential addresses and had to get the new data for the next address in that period of time and would demand high serial port speeds, etc, the reality is you can pound the same address over and over again with the same data and the flash wont start to program the page, and the download interface can be infinitely slow.  Serial flashes work differently and either dont need tricks or have different tricks.

RAM/FLASH is not some industry term.  It likely means that .text is in rom (flash) and .data and .bss are in ram.  A copy of the initial state of .data will probably be on flash as well and copied to ram before main() is called, likewise .bss will be zeroed before main() is called.  look at crt0.S for most platforms in gnu sources (glibc, or is it gcc, I dont know) to get the gist of how the bootstrap works in a generic fashion.

A bootloader is not required to run linux or other operating systems, you dont NEED uboot, but it is quite useful.  Linux is pretty easy, you copy the kernel and root file system, either set some registers or some tags in memory or both then branch to the entry point in the kernel and linux takes over from there.  Because linux is so complicated it is desireable to have a complicated bootloader that can capitalize on high speed interfaces like ethernet (rather than being limited to serial or slower).

Answer (score 2):

I would add something regarding your question Q2.

Q2: Why there is a need for Bootloader to copy application to RAM and then run the application from RAM? What difficulties we will face if our application runs from FLASH?

It is not only about having SPI or similar serial external code memory (which is not that often anyway).

Even the external ROM/FLASH/EPROM/ connected to the usual high speed parallel bus will will prevent a system from running on a maximum clock (with zero wait state) even on the relatively slow MCUs due to the external memory access time. You would need 10 ns FLASH access time for the 100 MHz clock, which is not so easy to get (if economically possible at all). And you would agree that 100 MHz is not such a brain spinning speed any more :-)

That is why many MCU/CPU architectures are doing tricks with reading multiply instructions at once, or having internal cash, or doing whatever was needed to compensate for a slow external code memory. Only most older 8-bit architectures can execute the code directly from the flash memory ('in place').

Even if your only code memory was the internal Flash, something need to be done to speed it up. Take a look for example at this article:

http://www.iqmagazineonline.com/magazine/pdf/v_3_2_pdf/pg14-15-18-19-9Q6Phillips-Z.pdf

It desribes how the ARM7 has incorporated something they called MAM (Memory Accelerator Module). It is a good read, and you will find some measures there to speed up the code memory access for the specific ARM7 arhitecture (goes for most others):

1. Limit maximum clock frequency (from 80 MHz to about 20 MHz for the example in the article)
2. Insert wait-cycles during flash accesses
3. Use an instruction cache
4. Copy the program code from flash to RAM

Obviously, if the instruction cache was not an option (too small, or the clock too high) you are really left only with execution from the RAM, after relocating the code there at the start up.

There is an option also to run only specific section of code from the RAM, which could be specified to the linker. For the DSP (Digital System Processing) systems, there was really no option to run from the EPROM/FLASH even in the old days with clock around only few tens of MHz, let alone now.

Another issue is debugging, the options for debugging the code placed in ROM, or even Flash, are very limited (you have to move section of the code to RAM to be able to set a break point on most systems).

Answer (score 2):

Regarding Q2, one of the difficulties you may face executing from Flash is another code update.  If you are executing from the same block of Flash you are trying to update, the system will crash.  This depends on your system architecture (how your application and bootloader are organized in Flash) but may be particularly hard to avoid if you are trying to update the bootloader itself.